# Objective-c : Most efficient way to load a texture to OpenGL

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, core-graphics

Currently i load a texture in iOS using Image I/O and I extract its image data with Core Graphics. Then i can send the image data to OpenGL like this :

```
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture->width, texture->height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture->imageData);
```

The problem is that the Core Graphics part is really slow, i need to setup and draw with Core Graphics just to extract the image data...i don't want to show it on screen. There must be a more efficient way to extract image data in iOS?...

Here is my code :

```
...
myTexRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, myOptions);
...
MyTexture2D* texture;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

void *imageData = malloc( tileSize.width * tileSize.height * 4 );

CGContextRef imgContext = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, tileSize.width, tileSize.height, 8, 4 * tileSize.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
CGContextClearRect( imgContext, CGRectMake( 0, 0, tileSize.width, tileSize.height ) );
CGContextTranslateCTM( imgContext, 0, 0 );
...
CGImageRef tiledImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect (imageRef, tileArea);
CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, tileSize.width, tileSize.height);

// *** THIS CALL IS REALLY EXPENSIVE!
CGContextDrawImage(imgContext, drawRect, tiledImage);

CGImageRelease(tiledImage);

// TamTexture2D takes the ownership of imageData and will be responsible to free it
texture = new MyTexture2D(tileSize.width, tileSize.height, imageData);

CGContextRelease(imgContext);
```

Comment: Your code seems to do more than just loading image data (tiling?) You should post the full code if you want help with optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for iOS 5 and above, [`GLKTextureLoader`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKTextureLoader_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010922) is what you're looking for:

Comment: Thx for the tip, i tried it but i keep getting this error message when trying to load a texture, i tried to call it statically and using the instance method initWithSharegroup... (im using opengl 1.1) :Texture Error:Error Domain=GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain error 8.)" UserInfo=0x10bef750 {GLKTextureLoaderGLErrorKey=1280, GLKTextureLoaderErrorKey=OpenGL error}...

Comment: Ah! that might explains it...so Richard your answer is useful but i am using OpenGL 1.1...I will look into Core Image framework maybe I'll find something

Answer (score 1):

GLKTextureLoader is orders of magnitude slower than using CG.

I have logged this as a bug with Apple DTS, and got it thrown back as "yes, we know, don't care, not going to fix it. You should be using CoreGraphics instead if you want your textures to be loaded fast" (almost that wording)

glTexImage2D is immensely fast if you give it the raw buffer that CGContext* methods create for you / allow you to pass in. Assuming you get the RGBA/ARGB/etc colour-spaces correct, of course.

cgcontextDrawImage is also super fast. My guess is that it's taking time to load your data over the web...